# How to align radio buttons on a Iphone safari

Tags: iphone, html, css, radio-button, alignment

I'm trying to horizontally align radio buttons below their label.  The code works fine on chrome on my desktop but not on a Iphone either on safari or chrome.  Here's the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/8wq4ba07/3/)

```
<div>

<div class='m' >
    <h3 class='m1'>RES</h3>
    <h3 class='m1'>SAIL</h3>
    <h3 class='m1'>Crew</h3>
    <h3 class='m1'>XCL</h3>
</div>

    <div class='m'>
        <input  class='n1' type="radio" name="rsx" id="r" value="res">
        <input  class='n1' type="radio" name="rsx" id="r" value="sail">
        <select id='n2'   name="crewopen">
        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3 </option>
        <option value="4">4 </option>
        <option value="5">5 </option>
        <option value="6">6 </option>

        </select>
        <input class='n1' type="radio" name="rsx" id="r" value="xcl">
    </div>

</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.m{
clear:both;
margin:0 auto;
width:85%;
text-align:center;
}

.m1{
float:left;
width:25%;   
margin:0;
}

.n1{   
width:25%; 
float:left;
text-align:right;    
margin:0;
 -webkit-appearance: radio;
}

#n2{
float:left;
width:15%;
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:5%;
}
```

Comment: I am using tailwind and I put a `items-center` on the div that contains the label and input, which did the trick for me in safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horizontally and vertically align radio input with their label. This code working is fine on iPhone on both Safari and Chrome.

```
<input  class="radio-button" type="radio" name="sn"  value="yes">

    .radio-button{
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        -webkit-appearance: radio;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, not a lot of interest in this one!  Any way the answer (or at least one that works)

```
.n1{

 width:5%;
 margin-left:10%;
 margin-right:10%
 }
```

also, if you're using bootstrap you need to add:

```
input[type=radio]{
margin-left:10%
margin-right:10%
}
```

and you can remove the margin attributes in .n1